# Google Cloud Composer BigQuery Operator- Get Jobs API HTTPError 404

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to run a BigQueryOperator on GCC. 
I have already succeeded in running for BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator and BigQueryTableDeleteOperator.

Here is my code for the dag:

```
import datetime
import os
import logging


from airflow import configuration
from airflow import models
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import email_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_check_operator
from airflow.utils import trigger_rule
from contextlib import suppress
import json
from airflow.operators import python_operator

yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1),
    datetime.datetime.min.time())

default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately when it is
    # detected in the Cloud Storage bucket.
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'project_id' : 'censored',
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

bq_dataset_name= 'test_tf_blocket'
bq_githib_table_id = bq_dataset_name + '.trialtable'

# [START composer_quickstart_schedule]
with models.DAG(
        dag_id='composer_nicholas',
        # Continue to run DAG once per day
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
    # [END composer_quickstart_schedule]

    def greeting():
        logging.info('Hello World!')

    hello_python = python_operator.PythonOperator(
            task_id='hello',
            python_callable=greeting)

    bq_union_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_union_query',
        bql="""
        select * from test_tf_blocket.nicholas_union_query;
        """,
        query_params={})

    email_start = email_operator.EmailOperator(
        task_id='email_it',
        to='nicholas@censored.my',
        subject='Sample temail',
        html_content="""
        Done.
        """)

    hello_python >> bq_union_query >> email_start
```

The dag fails when it hits the bigqueryOperator with the error(log) :

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://asia-south1-staging-b017f2bf-bucket/logs/composer_nicholas/bq_union_query/2019-03-21T14:56:45.453098+00:00/30.log.
[2019-03-22 13:12:54,129] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: composer_nicholas.bq_union_query 2019-03-21T14:56:45.453098+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-03-22 13:12:54,167] {models.py:1361} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: composer_nicholas.bq_union_query 2019-03-21T14:56:45.453098+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-03-22 13:12:54,168] {models.py:1573} INFO -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 30 of 3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-03-22 13:12:54,199] {models.py:1595} INFO - Executing <Task(BigQueryOperator): bq_union_query> on 2019-03-21T14:56:45.453098+00:00
[2019-03-22 13:12:54,200] {base_task_runner.py:118} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run composer_nicholas bq_union_query 2019-03-21T14:56:45.453098+00:00 --job_id 571 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/nicholas_union_query.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmpn1ic1w_6']
[2019-03-22 13:13:06,400] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:06,400] {settings.py:176} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800
[2019-03-22 13:13:08,433] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:08,431] {default_celery.py:80} WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of redis://airflow-redis-service:6379/0, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
[2019-03-22 13:13:08,435] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:08,435] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-03-22 13:13:09,182] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:09,181] {app.py:51} WARNING - Using default Composer Environment Variables. Overrides have not been applied.
[2019-03-22 13:13:09,198] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:09,198] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-03-22 13:13:09,210] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:09,210] {configuration.py:516} INFO - Reading the config from /etc/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2019-03-22 13:13:09,873] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:09,873] {models.py:271} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/gcs/dags/nicholas_union_query.py
[2019-03-22 13:13:12,207] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py:2412: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to BigQueryOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
[2019-03-22 13:13:12,208] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query *args: ()
[2019-03-22 13:13:12,208] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query **kwargs: {'api_resource_config': {'useQueryCache': True, 'jobType': 'QUERY'}}
[2019-03-22 13:13:12,208] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   category=PendingDeprecationWarning
[2019-03-22 13:13:12,209] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py:151: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in Task id: bq_union_query. Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow.
[2019-03-22 13:13:12,210] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   category=DeprecationWarning)
[2019-03-22 13:13:16,838] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:16,838] {cli.py:484} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: composer_nicholas.bq_union_query 2019-03-21T14:56:45.453098+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-7c9b9c7f86-xwhg5
[2019-03-22 13:13:17,455] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:17,453] {bigquery_operator.py:159} INFO - Executing: 
[2019-03-22 13:13:17,457] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query         select * from test_tf_blocket.nicholas_union_query;
[2019-03-22 13:13:17,457] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query         
[2019-03-22 13:13:17,632] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:17,632] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:92} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2019-03-22 13:13:17,657] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:17,656] {discovery.py:272} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest
[2019-03-22 13:13:18,336] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py:559: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in `BigQueryBaseCursor.run_query` Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow
  category=DeprecationWarning)
[2019-03-22 13:13:18,338] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:18,336] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py:559: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated parameter `bql` used in `BigQueryBaseCursor.run_query` Use `sql` parameter instead to pass the sql to be executed. `bql` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Airflow.
[2019-03-22 13:13:18,338] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   category=DeprecationWarning)
[2019-03-22 13:13:18,360] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:18,359] {discovery.py:873} INFO - URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/censored-analytics-censored/jobs?alt=json
[2019-03-22 13:13:18,885] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:18,884] {discovery.py:873} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/censored-analytics-censored/jobs/job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS?alt=json
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,341] {models.py:1760} ERROR - ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404)
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1014, in run_with_configuratio
    jobId=self.running_job_id).execute(
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrappe
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execut
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/censored-analytics-censored/jobs/job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS?alt=json returned "Not found: Job censored-analytics-censored:job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred

Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 180, in execut
    time_partitioning=self.time_partitionin
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 651, in run_quer
    return self.run_with_configuration(configuration
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1036, in run_with_configuratio
    err.resp.status
Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,347] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:20,341] {models.py:1760} ERROR - ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1014, in run_with_configuration
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     jobId=self.running_job_id).execute()
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/censored-analytics-censored/jobs/job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS?alt=json returned "Not found: Job censored-analytics-censored:job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS">
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query 
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,349] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,349] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query 
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,349] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,349] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 180, in execute
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     time_partitioning=self.time_partitioning
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 651, in run_query
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     return self.run_with_configuration(configuration)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1036, in run_with_configuration
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,350] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     err.resp.status)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,351] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,352] {models.py:1783} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,352] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query [2019-03-22 13:13:20,352] {models.py:1783} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,400] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,400] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1014, in run_with_configuration
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,403] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     jobId=self.running_job_id).execute()
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,405] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,406] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,407] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,408] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,409] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/censored-analytics-censored/jobs/job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS?alt=json returned "Not found: Job censored-analytics-censored:job_Nh77hL-CG3GHYCfWZY2Fhz4PgLlS">
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,409] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query 
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,410] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,411] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query 
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,411] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,411] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,412] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,412] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,413] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     args.func(args)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,414] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,414] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,415] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 490, in run
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,416] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,416] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 406, in _run
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,417] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     pool=args.pool,
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,418] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,420] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,421] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,421] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,421] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 180, in execute
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,422] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     time_partitioning=self.time_partitioning
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,422] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 651, in run_query
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,425] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     return self.run_with_configuration(configuration)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,425] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1036, in run_with_configuration
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,427] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query     err.resp.status)
[2019-03-22 13:13:20,427] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 571: Subtask bq_union_query Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404)
```

If I had typed a different sql query, for eg ( delete table ), the query would work. I am doing a select query here for simplicity. Point is, the sql query in here works, but the dag fails. It would seem that the dag has failed to retrieve the query history/job history from BQ. I checked if the json file exist, and yes it did. Heres a screen shot

[BQ SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI92j.png)

Initially I thought this was a permission issue, but i checked and the cloud composer generated service account has project owner rights and BQ admin rights.
I've tried searching around but cannot seem to find an answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also to add, I get the same error on the BigQueryCheckOperator.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, The error you get is `not Found` which means BigQuery couldn't find your table in the `location` set in the Job. Can you confirm if you are using the correct `location` (Default is US and if not in US you need to specify it in your call) and have no spelling (case sensitive) issue with your `project/ dataset /  table` names

Comment: I doubt it since it is able to run working queries in my tables, meaning it knows where my current tables are. The query history table is a temp table to store all query run information which the composer can't find. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm your table location is US by adding a screen shot of your table info from the webui to your question

Comment: Just double checked. My BQ zone/location is located at the asia-southeast1 (SG) region while my GCC is located at the asia-south1 (India) location. Will make a new environment with the correct location and try again.

Comment: Great I believe that will solve your problem. For good order I post this comment as an answer hope this will solve your issue and will appreciate if you can accept and vote up my answer if so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your BigQuery dataset resides in asia-southeast1, BigQuery created a job in the same location by default, which is asia-southeast1. However, the Airflow in your Composer environment was trying to get the job's status without specifying location field.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get

This has been fixed by my PR and it has been merged to master, and it will be released in v2.0.0. However, Composer's latest Airflow version is v1.10.2, so you need a work around to make it work.

To work around this, you can extend the BigQueryCursor and override the run_with_configuration() function with location support. Please refer to: 
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/4695/files#diff-ee06f8fcbc476ea65446a30160c2a2b2R1213 and check how to patch it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, A little help here. Does that mean I have to create a new custom operator which can state the location ?

Comment: You will need:
1) a new BigQueryHook extending Airflow's BigQueryHook, and have my fixed run_with_configuration() overridden the old one;
2) a new BigQueryOperator that extend Airflow's BigQueryOperator, and import the new BigQueryHook inside the new BigQueryOperator

Comment: You don't need to specify the location. The bug you've got is caused by BQHook submitting a job with the location where your dataset resides, and querying the status of the job without specifying that location. So with the fixed run_with_configuration(), it will query the job's status with the specified location.

Comment: Hello, little help, I am facing the same issue. I tried to patch BigQueryHook and import it into my own BQOperator and DAG, but that didn't work. I also tried copying the entire BQOperator.py and BQHook.py from Airflow open source, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for getting back!

The error occurs in line 60 of "MyBQHook" (initialisation of BQHook using super).


To give context...
I copied "BQHook" from Airflow 1.10.3, and named it "MyBQHook"
Also copied the entire "BQoperator" from Airflow 1.10.3, and replaced all calls for "BQHook" with "MyBQHook", and saved this as "MyBQOperator"

Comment: severity:  "INFO"  
 textPayload:  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 285, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/MyBigQueryOperator.py", line 22, in <module>
    from MyBigQueryHook2 import MyBigQueryHook2
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/MyBigQueryHook2.py", line 60
    super(, self).__init__(
"  
 timestamp:  "2019-06-17T10:24:13.355981388Z"  
}

Comment: Does this mean I have to copy the updated googlecloudbasehook file as well?

Comment: @Sciffany In MyBigQueryHook2, it seems like you are parsing a timestamp into init()?

Comment: I am having the same issue on Cloud Composer 2 (Airflow v2.2.5) when running `BigQueryToGCSOperator` even though I specify the `location`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @RyanTheCoder, I have created custom plugin with fix. Find it here [plugin code](https://github.com/JD-V/BQCustomPlugin). The readme file will show you how to use it.

Comment: It would have been better if you name your plugin in the snake case.