# Airflow - BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s'

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm in the southamerica-east1 location of BigQuery and when I try to run the airflow function GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator I get the error message: BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was:% s'

Searching on the topic I need to "force" the location of the BigQueryCursor operation table that I'm transferring to BigQuery.

Even creating an empty table with the same location I can not import the data that is in Cloud Storage.

I would like to understand in more detail what I need to do in my code (if possible by example) in order to successfully complete my process.

I reinforce that my dataset and the empty table are configured with the same location

```
json_gcs_to_bq = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq',
    bucket='big-data',
    source_objects=[nm_arquivo],
    destination_project_dataset_table='teste.tab1',
    schema_object='sc_tab1.json',
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    bigquery_conn_id='gcp_conn',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_conn',
    dag=dag
)
```

Error Message:

```
 [2019-06-21 14:39:38,639] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-06-21
 14:39:38,630] {{discovery.py:873}} INFO - URL being requested: POST
 https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/big-data/jobs?alt=json
 [2019-06-21 14:39:39,525] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-06-21
 14:39:39,525] {{discovery.py:873}} INFO - URL being requested: GET
 https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/big-data/jobs/job_zyDDpy94ReP_X6qqR6DrbqGnb-Ar?alt=json
 [2019-06-21 14:39:39,881] {{models.py:1760}} ERROR - ('BigQuery job
 status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404) Traceback (most recent
 call last):   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-ackages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py",
 line 1014, in run_with_configuration
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Composer BigQuery Operator- Get Jobs API HTTPError 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300785/google-cloud-composer-bigquery-operator-get-jobs-api-httperror-404)

Comment: @RyanTheCoder, i don´t understood the answer: show me please a example, how i put the BigQueryCursor operator in my script for solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted the functions gcs_to_bq and bigquery_hook locally, out of the airflow library and I made and forced the location for my region (in the southamerica-east1 case) and managed to make the process work!