# Airflow - Load Parquet table into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, parquet

I need advice!

I'm trying to load a parquet file located in a Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery by using the Apache Airflow GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.

My code is:

```
export_transactions_to_bq_task = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="export_transactions_parquet_to_bq",
        bucket="tempo-io-datalake-delivery",
        source_objects=["bigquery/atlassian/export_transactions.parquet"],
        destination_project_dataset_table="datalake-tempo-io:atlassian.transactions",
        source_format="PARQUET",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        autodetect=False,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        bigquery_conn_id="bigquery_default",
        dag=export_transactions_dag
        )
```

The parquet format doesn't need any schema specification because it is self-describing (?!) but Airflow give me an error that one of schema_fields, schema_object or autodetect settings must be provided.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug which has been fixed in Airflow v1.10.5 with this [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5771)

Since [the logic in the gcs_to_bq operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.5/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.py#L229) is having schema_object as None, schema_fields as None, and a default False value for autodetect, it will always throw that exception.

If you don't want to upgrade your Airflow to 1.10.5, setting **autodetect=True** would be the workaround.

Comment: I've tried with autodetect=True but it still doesn't work. I can't move with a new version of Airflow because I'm using the Google Cloud Composer and the current version is 1.10.2.

Comment: @Dataland I am lost here. So that error message will only be thrown `if not self.schema_fields and self.schema_object is None and self.autodetect is False`. So assuming you have None for both schema_fields and schema_object, but autodetect is True, it doesn't make sense you could still see that error. Reference: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.py#L208

Comment: Sorry @RyanTheCoder. I wasn't explaining myself clearly. The error I obtain is: Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404. It's like as if the operator can't find BigQuery resource?

Comment: @Dataland Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300785/google-cloud-composer-bigquery-operator-get-jobs-api-httperror-404

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your disposition is set to `create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED"`.

You can try setting autodetect=True or change the disposition to `CREATE_NEVER`. If you set the autodetect to True then the schema is inferred from the parquet file and if you change the disposition to `CREATE_NEVER` then the schema is inferred from the Bigquery table `"datalake-tempo-io:atlassian.transactions"`.

Let me know if that helps

Thanks,
jjayadeep

Comment: The usage of the disposition CREATE_NEVER suppose that I already have a table with the proper schema in BigQuery.

I want to create a table from the parquet file. I can do this manually in the Google Console without any problem with this parquet file but I want to automate the process with Airflow.

Still looking for a viable solution!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According with your error description which is "Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s'" the issue seems to be related with the job location and Bigquery Dataset location, as @RyanTheCoder mentioned, you should check the next [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300785/google-cloud-composer-bigquery-operator-get-jobs-api-httperror-404) and it might solve your issue.