# BigQueryCheckOperator failed with 404 Error in Cloud composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using BigQueryCheckOperator in Airflow to know if the data exists in BQ Table, but the Dag is failing with this `ERROR - <HttpError 404 when requesting https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/`

[Here is the logs of the Dag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngz5A.png)

Can Someone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi SRK. Your post would benefit from more information about what it is you're doing. Can you add the code and commands you're running to get this error? Please [avoid using images for code and logs](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Instead, [format your code and logs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in the post.  You may benefit from reading the post on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is known Airflow issue querying Bigquery datasets residing in non multi-regional locations (*US,EU*) within some of Bigquery operator [submodules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/index.html#submodules), the pull request [#8273](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8273) has been already raised.

You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300785/google-cloud-composer-bigquery-operator-get-jobs-api-httperror-404) Stack thread for most accurate problem explanation.

By now, it was announced to bring this problem fixed in Airflow 2.0 release, however community group has been pushed [*Backport package*](https://github.com/apache/airflow#backport-packages) in order to help the users with older Airflow 1.10.* versions and it will be considered in further building Airflow images for GCP Composer.

Looking for a workaround, you can try to adjust `BashOperator` invoking `bq` [command-line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference) tool in attempt to perform the certain action against Bigquery dataset inside the particular DAG file.